# Getting session data in SAPUI5 from Java servelet

Tags: java, session, cookies, sapui5

I have Java servelet:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
    throws ServletException, IOException {  

response.setContentType("text/html");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

String n=request.getParameter("username");  
String p=request.getParameter("userpass"); 

HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session!=null)
session.setAttribute("name", n);

if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){  
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("indexLogged.html");  
    rd.forward(request,response);  
}  
else{  
    out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>"); 
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");  
    rd.include(request,response);  
}  

out.close();  
}
```

When I log in application Servelet creates session and cookie, (like: Cookie:JSESSIONID=15CA73274C02C33E2C402DD7),  and I want to retrieve some data from this session in SAPUI5, how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In genral you add the data you want to receive in your response:

```
response.getWriter().print("some data");
```

The in your SAPUI5 application you make a ajax call;

```
$.ajax({
        url : mai_data.request_url + "&task=" + name,
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "text",
        data : "some upload data",
        success : function(oData) { } //oData contains the response text
        error : function(oData) { } //oData contains the response text
```

})

However in your case I think you initially go to the Login servlet and use this for a login and want to create . The you are redirected to the indexLogged.html and want to access some of the cockie data there. Since you inclded the request and response via:

```
 rd.include(request,response);
```

you should have access to the response data within the indexLogged.html.